# C# Clean Architecture - Best approach for creating abstractions

Tags: c#, .net, clean-architecture

I've received different opinions on this topic so I decided to come here and ask the question.
I have a relatively old codebase written on the .NET Framework that I must migrate to .NET 6 with Clean Architecture.

In the **application layer** I have a big messy helper class that uses lots of services and other classes with logic that are instantiated on the spot.

*CacheService cacheService = new CacheService()*

*StepExecutor stepExecutor = new StepExecutor();*

*CacheInvalidator cacheInvalidator = new CacheInvalidator();*

etc...

The implementation of those classes should now be moved to the **infrastructure layer**.

So, for the services I've created contracts in the **application layer** and moved the implementation in the **infrastructure layer** and I've injected them through the constructor of the gigantic helper class. All good.

My concern is for the other types of classes, some examples: manager, helpers, invalidator, executor, handler classes.  ( CacheInvalidator, StepExecutor, WorkflowManager, EventHandler )

What is the best approach for adding an abstraction layer for these classes? Also make them as services and inject them trough the constructor? Should I use factories? Wrappers? I would highly appreciate any insight on this subject. Any opinion, any documentation.
Personally, I think that this class should be entirely rewritten and split.

I'm really sorry if this is a really dumb question, I didn't manage to find a similar scenario as mine, most of the things I've found are only on small projects with 2 services where an abstraction layer is added and that's all. It's my first time doing something like this.

Thanks in advance and I hope this will maybe help someone in the future!

Comment: In one of the books I read (forget the title now) the author explained that classes named -or/-er often were misnomers, signs of an incorrect class architecture. There is some of that going on with `CacheService`, `StepExecutor`, `CacheInvalidator`, `WorkflowManager` -- shouldn't those be `Cache`, `Step`, and `Workflow`, with methods like `Cache.Validate()`, `Step.Execute()`, and `Workflow.Manage()`?

Comment: Would this be a good question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with you, the naming convention of those classes and the tasks that they perform are questionable. Still, with the change you mentioned, how is the application layer able to reach a concrete implementation? Let's say we have Cache ( this resides in infrastructure ) and I create the ICache contract ( in application ). I guess the way to go is the constructor but I'll have a 20 parameters constructor :') I'll post the question there also and big thanks for the response!

Comment: Perhaps you could group those constructor parameters into classes of their own? Likely, they must be related. Perhaps some of those values can be passed to the method doing the work as well (like `Cache.Validate(x, y, z)`)?

Comment: You can create a factory class that handles the injection/creation of the classes and then inject that factory into your constructors. That way you don't have 20 parameters in each constructor.

Comment: I will look more into trying to create a factory that creates multiple types of objects, sounds like a way nicer way of doing things. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The first decision you will have to make for these other classes (managers, helpers, handlers, ...) is: which layer should this code go? Is it all about business logic? Then it should remain in the application layer and you can use those directly or though interfaces and factories.

Should those classes be considered as "infrastructure"? things you want to keep away from the business logic? then follow the approach you already described (interfaces in application layer, implementation goes to infrastructure layer).

Probably - not unlikely in legacy code bases - such classes tend to be "in the middle": some aspects could be considered as business logic, others as infrastructure. then u should take the effort and split the classes and then continue as described above.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. The classes above belong to the infrastructure layer, I was curious about a good practice of getting to them trough abstractions.  I could've just register them and injected trough the constructor. That's not an issue but the constructor would've had 30 parameters and I was curious if there is another nicer way.

Comment: Currently I'm migrating the code from a monolith without trying to refactor too much. That will be the next step. And regards classes  that tend to be "in the middle", I've got some of that, mostly extensions and entities, fortunately nothing serious. :D

Comment: to use these classes in the business logic you probably want to create appropriate interfaces in application layer and then inject the classes through these interfaces. constructor injection is usually preferred for mandatory dependencies. if you end up with constructors having too many parameters then the consuming class usually has too many responsibilities and should be refactored.

Comment: "the consuming class usually has too many responsibilities and should be refactored" that's exactly the case here :(